# CSS backgroung no-repeat, but there is a white space

Tags: html, background, css

I have a problem with my site.

There is a css code that display a gradient as Background for my webpage.

With the option: "background-repeat:no-repeat;", If the webpage rendered is more little than the space that a browser can display, there is a white space at the bottom of the page.

If i delete this option, the background is repeated but the gradient start over again, so the result is horrible. Like:

```
Blue
<Content of the rendered page>
Red
Blue
Red
```

The only solution that i have found is to make a gradient to white, and disable the repeat.
So the white space seems the end of the gradient.

But i need these colors, so any suggestion? Can i change the white spot with a color?

Thank you.

UPDATE: I changed the colors of my site with the suggested link, but the gradient repeat like ever.

Comment: If your gradient ends with red at the bottom, why not set the page background to red, thereby creating the illusion that the gradient never ends? `background: #FF0000 url(/gradient.png) no-repeat;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this will help?

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to build a gradient things,

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Look here when background-repeat works

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-repeat&preval=no-repeat